# django: метод reverse не определён

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Вылетает вот такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

объявил в модели метод get_absolute_url, для передачи url в шаблон, но метод reverse почему то не работает

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("movie_detail", kwargs = {"slug" : self.url})
```

Comment: возможно reversed() ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте в скрипт импорт:

```
from django.urls import reverse
```

Подробнее: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import reverse

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("movie_detail", args = (self.url,))
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]